# Looking for a better way to authenticate hashed username & password in offline mode

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, hash, dart-isolates

I've got this nice pretty little function for offline authentication but its very heavy on the processor due to hashing checks. As part of my offline-first strategy I'm storing User models in an encrypted Hive box. I am checking against this when offline.

I tried putting the heavy process into an isolate compute() function, through errors I discovered [HERE](https://bleepcoder.com/hive/521106302/using-hive-db-in-a-background-process) that Hive does not support multi-threading. I'm sure this could be done with a lot of code and ports and separate Hive initializations but this makes my head spin thinking of it. Also having an encrypted sensitive file who knows where in memory doesn't sound secure.

So I want to see if there are any clever or obvious solutions to this. Because I am confused. I am worried about security of the contents if I were to send an unencrypted list to iterate through in an isolate, for example if I sent the encryptedBox to isolate unencrypted and ran the loop there.

Any ideas?

Code:

Hive encryption code [HERE](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box)

```
// Offline auth method
  Future<bool> offlineAuthentication(String userName, String password) async {
    
    ... // STANDARD HIVE ENCRYPTED BOX DECRYPTION

    bool authorized = false;
    final DBCrypt hashing = DBCrypt();

    for (final user in encryptedBox.values) {
      (hashing.checkpw(userName, user.userName) && hashing.checkpw(password, user.password))
          ? authorized = true
          : authorized = false;
    }
    return authorized;
  }
```

Hashing info:

Package is [BDCrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/dbcrypt)

I am using like so with 12 round salt: `String salt = dBCrypt.gensaltWithRounds(12);`

Comment: Skimming over `hashing.checkpw` , it doesn't look stateful, so it seems rather wasteful to check hashes for each element of `encryptedBox.values` when your function returns the result only for the last element.

Comment: "Also having an encrypted sensitive file who knows where in memory doesn't sound secure." If you're concerned about unencrypted data being copied in memory and not necessarily being zeroed when deallocated, then you probably shouldn't be using a garbage-collected language that does all memory management for you. =/ I don't think that sending unencrypted data to another isolate is necessarily any worse than having unencrypted data in the main isolate.

Comment: Security comment: makes sense, I think I was fishing for professional input- I got it now. Thanks! As for the function please allow me to clarify. The encrypted box would store a few user objects, in the scenario one device has a few accounts. these are being iterated through here unless I’m mistaken. This is how I’m currently authenticating for offline. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: You iterate over multiple items, but you don't stop when you find a matching username/password.  You ultimately iterate over all items and return only the last result.

Comment: Oops! Didn’t notice that. I will throw in a break. Sometimes I get too attached to how nice and organized ternary operator looks I miss things.