# Memory encryption and memory zero unknowns- assist my understanding

Tags: flutter, dart, security, encryption

I want to protect my users data as much as possible! In this scenario I'm trying to protect data-in-use/data-in-memory against certain memory attacks or at least make it more difficult for nefarious people to get at my users' data.

I do not really understand how Flutter & Dart handle memory or really any language for that matter. So I'm looking for some insight, direction or confirmation in what I'm trying to do here without needing a masters in computer science. While I'm using Flutter/Dart this is also a generalized question.

My modus operandi here is simple, when done with some sensitive data I want to:

1. Encrypt data for memory zero
2. Zero all encrypted memory

Does this do what I intend?

If this does not do what I intend or is pointless in any way, please explain why.

```
/*
    - Symmetric encryption
    - Encryption before putting data into transit
    - This symmetric key and nonce are asymmetrically encrypted with authorized users public keys
    - Authorized users can decrypt the key
    - Sensitive data is encrypted then zeroed
  */
  Future<String> symmetricallyEncrypt(Sale sale) async {
    String saleJson = jsonEncode(sale);
    final symmetricKey = await secureStorage.read(key: kSSKeySymmetric);
    final symmetricNonce = await secureStorage.read(key: kSSKeySymmetricNonce);
    final symmetricCypher = AesCrypt(padding: PaddingAES.pkcs7, key: symmetricKey!);
    final encryptedSale = symmetricCypher.gcm.encrypt(inp: saleJson, iv: symmetricNonce!);

    /* --- ENCRYPTED ZERO --- */
    encryptedZero(saleJson);
    encryptedZero(symmetricKey);
    encryptedZero(symmetricNonce);
    encryptedZero(symmetricCypher.toString());

    return encryptedSale;
  }

  /*
    Encryption zero method
      - Encrypts shredding input
      - Zeros all inputs
  */
  Future<void> encryptedZero(String shredding) async {
    String? asymmetricPublicZeroKey = await secureStorage.read(key: kSSKeyMemoryZeroAsymmetricPublic);
    String encryptedShredding = RSAPublicKey.fromPEM(asymmetricPublicZeroKey!).encrypt(shredding);
    asymmetricPublicZeroKey = '';
    encryptedShredding = '';
    shredding = '';
  }
```

Comment: [As I alluded to before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68538390/), I think it's a lost cause.  Note that `shredding = '';` does not zero any memory; it simply assigns `shredding` to an empty `String` object, and the old `String` object will be freed like any other object by the garbage collector.  Furthermore, `String`s are immutable, and you have no control over whether they (or any other Dart object) are copied or moved in memory.

Comment: My man james at it again! Thats really the exact answer I was looking for. You have any resources that can help me study up on how Dart handles memory? Or any other general material? I'd like to put this to rest with some deeper understanding.

Comment: Also do you know of any way to force garbage collection in Dart? dispose()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you're asking but think it's not the right way to think about the security of your memory.

What's the threat actor - another process? The operating system? The root user?

If you don't trust the root user, the OS, and the hardware, you've already lost.

If you have to trust them, then what else is your threat actor? You have to trust your application. So the only other things are other applications running on the same system.

The operating system prevents other applications from reading your memory space (SEG FAULT, etc). And the OS zeros out your application's memory pages before passing them to another process.

But that's not the whole story - read https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe for even more details.

Comment: Thats a really great answer. Very informative, thanks for pointing these out. Also the link you provided gave me tons of good additional information that answers the question further. As for threat actor, I pitch this as high up as possible because I sincerely care about my users' data. I don't want anything screwed up or exposed by a lone wolf hacker or much less read by the NSA- wether my users' or their data & my app would be a target or not, I hold information security as top priority! With reports of NSA/CIA gaining access to data before encryption, I get into a state of mind of PROTECT!